# check previous and current element of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Imagine: I have a an array: `["1", "2", "X", ".", "4", "3", "Z", "-", "12"];`

I consider which function should I use to:

- find first **NaN** element in array (let say index = 2) and check if the next (index = 3) is also **NaN** and if yes (delete from array element with index = 2).

So the result of the transformed array should be: `["1", "2",".", "4", "3", "-", "12"];`

I do not want your code, just suggestion/help how to start it.

Thank you for your responses and help.

Comment: add the code you have so far

Comment: not quite understand what you trying to ask for, are you trying to say filter out all the `NaN` element ?

Comment: @Dean filter all `NaN` if and only if the next element of the array is itself not a number.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca excatly. I wonder why I have -5 to this question... what's wrong with this?

Comment: @Ernesto the problem is that you didn't show any effort to solve this yourselves, which is frowned-upon here. Hence the downvotes.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca But I said I do not want a code :P, ok I will remember to write down code next time :).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca    

 equation = ["2", ".", "2", "*", "+", "-", "3"];
    desiredEquation = ["2", ".", "2", "-", "3"];  
          
    equation.reduce((acc, currChar, index, arr) => {
                    if (isNaN(currChar) && isNaN(arr[index+1])) {
                        arr.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                });
    expect(equation).toEqual(desiredEquation);


Received:
  ["2", ".", "2", "+", "-", "3"]

I was working on my own and it does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could just check the array for two following NaN values.

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "X", ".", "4", "3", "Z", "-", "12"],
    result = array.filter((v, i, a) => !isNaN(v) || !isNaN(a[i + 1]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate over the array and keep track of the `current` and `previous` element.

Then you can and use **[isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)** to check if both values ares `NaN` or not.

If both are `NaN`, you can then use **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** to remove the item at index `i-1` (the equivalent of `previous`):

```js
arr = ["1", "2", "X", ".", "4", "3", "Z", "-", "12"];

var previous = null;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var current = arr[i];
  if(isNaN(previous) && isNaN(current)) {
     arr.splice(i-1, 1);
  }
  previous = current;
}

console.log(arr); //[ '1', '2', '.', '4', '3', '-', '12' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find if current and next items are `NaN`.

```js
const data = ["1", "2", "X", ".", "4", "3", "Z", "-", "12", "END"];

const result = data.filter((c, i, arr) => i + 1 === arr.length || !(isNaN(c) && isNaN(arr[i + 1])));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it recursively:

```js
var arr = ["1", "2", "X", ".", "4", "3", "Z", "-", "12"];
var i = 0;
function removeFirstNan (arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(arr[i]) && isNaN(arr[i + 1])) {
      var newArr = [ ...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i + 1, arr.length) ];
      return removeFirstNan(newArr);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

arr = removeFirstNan(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

A more readable way with *array.prototype.findIndex* :

```js
var arr = ["1", "2", "X", ".", "4", "3", "Z", "-", "12"];
function removeFirstNan (arg) {
    var firstNanIndex = arg.findIndex((e, i) => (isNaN(e) && isNaN(arg[i + 1])));
    if (firstNanIndex !== -1) {
        var newArr = [ ...arg.slice(0, firstNanIndex), ...arg.slice(firstNanIndex + 1, arg.length) ];
        return removeFirstNan(newArr);
    }
    return arg;
}
arr = removeFirstNan(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You should stop the cycle one step before.

Comment: I forget the recursive call sorry